# Please help "data-ng-controller" is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I have write down below code but when i am using "data-ng-controller" then my code stop working else it works. Please suggest me what is going wrong with my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>AngularJS | Scope</title>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-ng-controller="Firstfunc">

<input data-ng-model="typename" type="text" /> {{ typename }}

<ul>
<li data-ng-repeat="view in Listing">{{view.name}} - {{view.singh}} </li>
</ul>

</div>

<script>
function Firstfunc ($scope){
$scope.Listing = [
{name:'Ajay Singh', age:'45'},
{name:'Rajeev Arora', age:'75'},
{name:'Nitesh Sharma', age:'26'},
{name:'Kalash Singh', age:'55'}
];
}
</script>
```

Comment: FirstFunc is not defined as an angular controller?

Comment: my friend i dont see any error , just created a plunkr and it is working well. :) have  look at the url,          http://plnkr.co/edit/qWyOeq40KekWbxC5Wb0K?p=preview

Comment: Global controllers were disabled in 1.3.0-beta.15: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-13

Comment: Please define "is not working".

Comment: For me it works: http://fiddle.jshell.net/719ayehj/; Try move function to js file and include it after angular include

Comment: I think it's not working locally... it needs local server setup

Comment: no need of any local server.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular you should create a module and add a controller to it. Yes controller is javascript constructor function, but you have assigned like in below format. hope this helps.

[DEMO HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/82AlrczNuWrkPB4Bswbg?p=preview)

```
<body data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="myController as ctrl">
        <input data-ng-model="typename" type="text" /> {{ typename }}
        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="view in Listing">{{view.name}} - {{view.singh}} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);

    app.controller('myController', function($scope){
        $scope.Listing = [
            {name:'Ajay Singh', age:'45'},
            {name:'Rajeev Arora', age:'75'},
            {name:'Nitesh Sharma', age:'26'},
            {name:'Kalash Singh', age:'55'}
        ];
    })
</script>
```

Comment: @user1838451 : Copy and paste the above code in local it will work. second - is your script paths is correct ?

Comment: My Function is also working on plunkr but it's not working on local system

Comment: are you defining your JS "<script src="angular.min.js"></script>" Path correctly or do you have the file in any folder .

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

This is occurring because i was using Angular 1.3v and now I am using Angular 1.2.6v and it's working fine.

Thanks everyone for your reply and support.